# CefSharp RegisterJsObject and non-static context

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have a window which contains a ChromiumWebBrowser.
Now I want to get a message from that Browser by a JavaScriptObject and when I get it, I want to look inside my list, what image, video or hyperlink I shall show next and then do exactly that.
There is only the problem of the static and non-static methods. the complete class and all methods inside where the browser is made filled are non-static. The JavascriptObject is static.
There are many examples out there that show how to create this object but not how to use it.
Now my question: "Is there any way of calling the Javascript inside the HTML to access non-static objects?"

edit:

Ok, I try to be more precise and detailed.
I have an app, which creates numerous windows, which are inheriting a ChromiumWebBrowser-object, an Image-object and a MediaElement-object.
When the window is created (and every few minutes afterwards) I read a XML-file (which can be edited by another user) that tells me what I shall show in my window. Some things are easy to do, like at the end of a video I look for the next item to show. But on websites its a little bit harder. So I searched and came up with the `JavaScriptObject` of the `ChromiumWebBrowser`. I implement it in the window right after the `InitializeComponent()` by this code:

```
FirstBrowser.RegisterJsObject("callbackObject", new JavaScriptCommunicationObject());
SecondBrowser.RegisterJsObject("callbackObject", new JavaScriptCommunicationObject());
```

Now I can use the follwing JavaScript to communicate with my app:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    callbackObject.callNextMedia('NextMedia');
</script >
```

Inside the window I declared a new class and a method. But this method is static, so I cannot call any methods from the mainclass:

```
public class JavaScriptCommunicationObject
{
    public void CallNextMedia(string message)
    {
        if (message.Equals("NextMedia"))
        {
            MixedMediaWindow.FileCounter++;
            MixedMediaWindow.ShowNextMedia();
        }
    }
}
```

I could make the `FileCounter` static, so I could change it from the second one. But I cannot call the ShowNextMedia(). So I wanted to ask if there is a way to call it by any direct means. I could set a static flag (boolean) and check it every few milliseconds for a change and if it was changed, so I could call the ShowNextMedia()-method from inside the `DispatcherTimer`. But I wanted to avoid too much Timers, a direct method-call would be much nicer.

Comment: It's not clear what your asking. What have you tried so far? Some `psudo` code would help if you haven't implement anything yet. Make sure you read the `FAQ` also.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question

Comment: So basically you want to call a `static` method? That's not supported. You can share the same bound class between two browser instances and use some basic locking.

Comment: Erm, no. I want to call a non-static method. But the only access I have is to the JavaScriptCommunicationObject and the CallNextMedia therin. But THAT is static, so I can't call any non-static methods anymore.

Comment: `CallNextMedia` is not static in the source you've provided, and wouldn't work if it was. So you've lost me, I've got no idea what your asking.

Comment: If you want to access another class, then just pass a reference to it into the constructor. Keep it private if you won't want it exposed, or store it as a public property if you want the binding to expose the object.